# Greenhouse job board integration on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

I want to integrate greenhouse job board on my company's wordpress website. All greenhouse configurations are in place. There are no reliable plugins in wordpress for this task. This is how the integrated section currently looks on my website: https://hunch.in/careers/ . How do i integrate it properly and beautify it? Something like what headout has - https://www.headout.com/careers/

Is there a complete HTML code for this?

I tried using the Greenhouse plugin on wordpress that was last updated 6 years ago. The implementation is not proper through that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did an integration with a site using the [Greenhouse Job Board](https://developers.greenhouse.io/job-board.html) API and using a combination of custom Gutenberg blocks with ACF, custom Wordpress rewrite rules (for our requirements), and the [Greenhouse PHP Library](https://github.com/grnhse/greenhouse-tools-php).

The code I wrote isn't mine to freely give away, but I can summarize what I did.

### Example Code To Get all Offices.

```
<?php
/* Initialize service and pass in our credentials */
$greenhouseService = new \Greenhouse\GreenhouseToolsPhp\GreenhouseService\GreenhouseService([
    'apiKey'     => '< YOUR API KEY >',
    'boardToken' => '< YOUR BOARD TOKEN >'
]);

/* Load all offices */
$response = $greenhouseService->getJobApiService()->getOffices();
/* 
   Note: the API does not auto-decode the JSON response. 
   This call includes all the jobs under each department per office. 
   You'll need to look at the documentation to see how they structure their responses.
 */
$offices = json_decode($response);

// do something with the response...
```

### Useful Hooks

With our project, we also had a requirement to put the application and job detail on a wordpress page. This was accomplished by designating a single page our "Job Detail" page and giving it some slug (in this example `/apply/`), and then using the following actions/filters/functions:

- `query_vars`: Register a query var to store our job ID that we establish in our rewrite rule.
- `add_rewrite_rule()`: Register `/apply/([0-9]+)?$` as a valid URL. Assign the Job ID to a query var in Wordpress for later use.
- `template_redirect`: Enqueue the scripts Greenhouse needs for the application form and verify the Job ID from the URL is valid.
- `the_content`: Replace the placeholder page content with info from the API.
- `pre_get_document_title`: Replace the placeholder page title with a custom page title (the position name).

This should hopefully give you a good idea of how to work with the Job Board API and how to implement it in Wordpress.

Comment: https://hunch.in/careers/

These are 4 questions i am looking answers for:

1) We have already developed the Careers page on our wordpress site. We are currently using Greenhouse Plugin by Brownbag Marketing, through which we are seeing the dashboard twice, one with CSS, one without CSS. Why is this happening?
2) Clicking on the apply button for any of the jobs hides the 2nd job board entirely. Why?
3) How to fix this?
4) Any particular plugin you recommend for wordpress? If not, how to integrate greenhouse dashboard on our website, if we opt for one of options 3-5 on their portal?

Comment: I can't help you really with that plugin and questions related to it. We rolled our own solution because we didn't feel a plugin would solve our requirements. If you want to roll your own, you'll need to start by reading the API docs on how to query jobs from the Job Board API.